# find_or_create_by versus before_save callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model that uses a callback to normalize one of its parameters, and that parameter is part of a unique key for the model.  But when using `MyModel.find_or_create_by()`, the callback doesn't come into play during the 'find' phase, only the 'create' phase, by which it's too late.

Is there an elegant pattern for doing this?  A contrived example:

```
class CreateMyModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_models do |t|
      t.float :value
    end
    add_index :my_models, :value, :unique => true
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :quantize_value
  private
    def quantize_value
      self.value = ((self.value || 0.0) * 256.0).round / 256.0
    end
end
```

Let's try it out:

```
>> a = MyModel.find_or_create_by(:value => 0.501)
=> #<MyModel id: 1, value: 0.5>
```

So far, so good.  If we find_or_create_by another whose value is close but not equal to the incumbent record, we'd like it to find the incumbent record.  But instead we get:

```
>> b = MyModel.find_or_create_by(:value => 0.5001)
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint ...
```

What I'd like -- conceptually -- is to have the quantize_value method run *before* running the find.

Of course I've already written a custom constructor that applies the quantize_value method before running the find.  But if experience has taught me anything, it's that the developers of Rails have already written the code that I think I need to write, and creating my own constructor would be replicating their work! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, I would move the quantize logic out of the models saving callbacks and do it manually. You'd be more aware of what the actual values are instead of setting a value and then seeing the model modifying it.

If you really want to keep the logic inside the model, you can override the setter method for your attribute like below:

```
def value=(val)
  self[:value] = quantitize_value(val)
end
```

Comment: "move the quantize logic out of the models" -- that's debatable: I'd claim that the quantization of the value is a function of the model, and should NOT be exposed to the caller.  But I'm doing something along the lines you propose with a custom constructor inside MyModel to hide those details from the caller.

Comment: If you really want to keep this inside the model then try overriding your value set method like def value=(val); @value=quantitize_value(value); end (replace ; by newlines indeed)

Comment: That sounds just right.  If you edit your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Close! Since the question is about rails and active records, I think the right answer is `def value=(val); self[:value] = quantize_value(val) ; end`.  Do you agree?

Comment: One teensy little detail: it doesn't work.  When doing the find() part of find_or_create, it doesn't call value= method.  So this still fails in the same manner as the O.P.  I'll give you the check mark anyway for your efforts, but hope to find a clean solution.

Comment: Ohh right forgot about that. then I guess you'll have to create your own custom class method. def self.create_with_value(val); val = quantitize_value(val); find_or_create_by(value: val); end. This makes sense?